# When loading a dll in Python does the dir function shows its methods?

Tags: python, methods, dllimport

Does this code shows the methods from a dll?

```
from ctypes import *
x = cdll.LoadLibrary("olari.dll")
dir(x)
```

if not, how can we see the .dll methods in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't. But It can cache when you call, and will show in `dir` after that.

You could take a look this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128150/win32-api-to-enumerate-dll-export-functions), even in Win32, seems like need to parse PE Header. I think python need to do similar way.

**UPDATE**:

I found [pefile read/write module](http://code.google.com/p/pefile/wiki/UsageExamples) written in python, there you can find exported entries.

```
for entry in pe.DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT:
  print entry.dll
  for imp in entry.imports:
    print '\t', hex(imp.address), imp.name
Output
comdlg32.dll
        0x10012A0L PageSetupDlgW
        0x10012A4L FindTextW
        0x10012A8L PrintDlgExW
[snip]
SHELL32.dll
        0x1001154L DragFinish
        0x1001158L DragQueryFileW
```

`imp.name` will be the one you are looking for. You could use that name in ctypes like

```
>>> ctypes.windll.comdlg32.PageSetupDlgW
<_FuncPtr object at 0x00A97210>
>>> ctypes.windll.comdlg32.FindTextW
<_FuncPtr object at 0x00A97288>
...
```

Comment: what code do I need to put before the one you gave for this to work?

Comment: Hi, you need to install that python library first - 
http://code.google.com/p/pefile/downloads/list