# Listing functions of an unmanaged DLL at runtime in c#

Tags: c#, reflection, dll, unmanaged

Is it possible to obtain a list of functions declared in an unmanaged DLL? I want to create this list in a c# program.

Using dumpbin or System.Reflection.Assembly is not possible.

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask, why can't you use dumpbin? In this case, using reflection is not an option as you've stated.

Comment: Of course reflection is not working. It's no .NET assembly.

Comment: I want to extract the information at runtime, with unknown DLLs. I want to use the information dumpbin provides, but in program code, not as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way you can do this either:

- Use a utility (such as dumpbin) and
  analyse its output from your C# code.
- Open the target DLL file and manually
  work out where the export section of
  the file is located and read that.

You might need the help of too like [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/overview.htm) or similar to help you get up and running by showing you location of the exports in a file.

If you want to do it without a utility, then you will need to understand the PE file format for a Windows DLL file and read the exports section.

Check out this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128150/win32-api-to-enumerate-dll-export-functions)