# How to we read the exports table from a dll using C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, windows, export

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Win32 API to enumerate dll export functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128150/win32-api-to-enumerate-dll-export-functions)

How do we read the exports table from a dll using C or C++?

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Odd that I couldn't find it

Comment: I misunderstood your question because you are missing a comma between using and C. So I thought you were look for a tool to read the exports table from a DLL where the DLL was written in C or C++ !!  :))

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way would be to invoke [Dumpbin /Exports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30e78zd0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on the DLL, and parse the output into the form you want.  Are your requirements more complex than this?

Comment: C will be undecorated. For C++ you will find "undname /show_flags" necessary to demangle.