# Is there a way to find the C++ mangled name to use in GetProcAddress?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

The common "solution" to use `GetProcAddress` with C++ is "extern "C", but that breaks overloading. Name mangling allows multiple functions to co-exist, as long as their signature differs. But is there a way to find these mangled names for `GetProcAddress`?

Answer (score 7):

The VC++ compiler knows its own name mangling scheme, so why not use that? Inside `template<typename T> T GetProcAddress(HMODULE h, const char* name)`, the macro `__FUNCDNAME__` contains the mangled name of `GetProcAddress`. That includes the `T` part. So, inside `GetProcAddress<void(*)(int)`, we have a substring with the mangled name of `void(*)(int)`. From that, we can trivially derive the mangled name of `void foo(int);`

This code relies on the VC++ macro `__FUNCDNAME__`. <strike>For MinGW you'd need to base this on `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` instead</strike>.

```
FARPROC GetProcAddress_CppImpl(HMODULE h, const char* name, std::string const& Signature)
{
    // The signature of T appears twice in the signature of T GetProcAddress<T>(HMODULE, const char*) 
    size_t len = Signature.find("@@YA");
    std::string templateParam = Signature.substr(0, len);
    std::string returnType    = Signature.substr(len+4);
    returnType.resize(templateParam.size()); // Strip off our own arguments (HMODULE and const char*)
    assert(templateParam == returnType); 
    // templateParam and returnType are _pointers_ to functions (P6), so adjust to function type (Y)
    std::string funName = "?" + std::string(name) + "@@Y" + templateParam.substr(2);
    return ::GetProcAddress(h, funName.c_str());
}

template <typename T>
T GetProcAddress(HMODULE h, const char* name)
{
    // Get our own signature. We use `const char* name` to keep it simple.
    std::string Signature = __FUNCDNAME__ + 18; // Ignore prefix "??$GetProcAddress@"
    return reinterpret_cast<T>(GetProcAddress_CppImpl(h, name, Signature));
}

// Showing the result

struct Dummy { };

__declspec(dllexport) void foo( const char* s)
{
    std::cout << s;
}

__declspec(dllexport) void foo( int i, Dummy )
{
    std::cout << "Overloaded foo(), got " << i << std::endl;
}

__declspec(dllexport) void foo( std::string const& s )
{
    std::cout << "Overloaded foo(), got " << s << std::endl;
}

__declspec(dllexport) int foo( std::map<std::string, double> volatile& )
{
    std::cout << "Overloaded foo(), complex type\n";
    return 42;
}

int main()
{
    HMODULE h = GetModuleHandleW(0);
    foo("Hello, ");
    auto pFoo1 = GetProcAddress<void (*)( const char*)>(h, "foo");
    // This templated version of GetProcAddress is typesafe: You can't pass 
    // a float to pFoo1. That is a compile-time error.
    pFoo1(" world\n");
    auto pFoo2 = GetProcAddress<void (*)( int, Dummy )>(h, "foo");
    pFoo2(42, Dummy()); // Again, typesafe.
    auto pFoo3 = GetProcAddress<void (*)( std::string const& )>(h, "foo");
    pFoo3("std::string overload\n");
    auto pFoo4 = GetProcAddress<int (*)( std::map<std::string, double> volatile& )>(h, "foo");
    // pFoo4 != NULL, this overload exists.
    auto pFoo5 = GetProcAddress<void (*)( float )>(h, "foo");
    // pFoo5==NULL - no such overload.
}
```

Comment: Note that `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` won't work that way as it's not mangled, it will look something like `T GetProcAddress(HMODULE, const char*)  [with T = blahblah]`. I'm not sure any such thing as a mangled function name macro exists at all under GCC (don't think so).

Comment: @Damon: You're right, I misread the documentation. There's indeed no such macro, and the `<cxxabi.h>` header only provides a de-mangle function.

Comment: @MSalters interesting but it didn't work on the function I tried it on because of a back reference in the mangled name in the dll, but not in your function; because the function is in a namespace, and returns an object of a class in the same namespace; in the return type the namespace name get's replaced with a @1 ...

Comment: for the record: name in the dll: ?myFunction@sfw@@YAAAVEStore@1@XZ name deduced by the templated GetProcAddress: ?myFunction@sfw@@YAAAVEStore@sfw@@XZ

Comment: @F4: Weird, what's `__FUNCDNAME__` inside `GetProcAddress<T>` ? I had expected it to have the same `@1` backreference.

Comment: @MSalters from wikipedia: "you can use a back reference to the function name in the function arguments (which appear after the function name). However, in the template argument list, the back reference table is separately created". As for __ FUNCDNAME __:??$GetProcAddress@P6AAAVEStore@sfw@@XZ@tools@@YAP6AAAVEStore@sfw@@XZPAXPBD@Z

Answer (score 4):

Use `dumpbin /exports 'file.dll'` to get the decorated / undecorated name of all the symbols.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do it just by using `GetProcAddress`. However, one way to do it would be to enumerate all the exported functions for that particular module, and do a pattern matching to find all the mangled names.

More specifically, refer to [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4354755/762123). The only change you will need to make would be to pass in `TRUE` for `MappedAsImage` parameter and the return value of `GetModuleHandle` for `Base` parameter to `ImageDirectoryEntryToData` function call.

```
void EnumerateExportedFunctions(HMODULE hModule, vector<string>& slListOfDllFunctions)
{
    DWORD *dNameRVAs(0);
    _IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY *ImageExportDirectory;
    unsigned long cDirSize;
    _LOADED_IMAGE LoadedImage;
    string sName;
    slListOfDllFunctions.clear();

    ImageExportDirectory = (_IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY*)
        ImageDirectoryEntryToData(hModule,
        TRUE, IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT, &cDirSize);
    if (ImageExportDirectory != NULL)
    {
        dNameRVAs = (DWORD *)ImageRvaToVa(LoadedImage.FileHeader, 
            LoadedImage.MappedAddress,
        ImageExportDirectory->AddressOfNames, NULL);
        for(size_t i = 0; i < ImageExportDirectory->NumberOfNames; i++)
        {
            sName = (char *)ImageRvaToVa(LoadedImage.FileHeader, 
                    LoadedImage.MappedAddress,
                   dNameRVAs[i], NULL);
         slListOfDllFunctions.push_back(sName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite fathom why you'd ever want/need a constexpr version of [MSalters' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16016860/4832499), but here it is, complete with namespace mangling. Use as

```cpp
using F = int(double*);
constexpr auto f = mangled::name<F>([]{ return "foo::bar::frobnicate"; });
constexpr const char* cstr = f.data();
```

where `F` is the function signature and `foo::bar::frobnicate` is the (possibly qualified) name of the function.

```cpp
#include<string_view>
#include<array>

namespace mangled
{
    namespace detail
    {
        template<typename F>
        inline constexpr std::string_view suffix()
        {
            auto str = std::string_view(__FUNCDNAME__);
            return str.substr(14, str.size() - 87);
        }
        
        template<typename L>
        struct constexpr_string
        {
            constexpr constexpr_string(L) {}
            static constexpr std::string_view data = L{}();
        };

        template<typename Name>
        inline constexpr int qualifiers()
        {
            int i = -2, count = -1;
            while(i != std::string_view::npos)
            {
                i = Name::data.find("::", i + 2);
                count++;
            }
            return count;
        }

        template<typename Name>
        inline constexpr auto split()
        {
            std::array<std::string_view, qualifiers<Name>() + 1> arr = {};
            int prev = -2;
            for(int i = arr.size() - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                int cur = Name::data.find("::", prev + 2);
                arr[i] = Name::data.substr(prev + 2, cur - prev - 2);
                prev = cur;
            }
            arr[0] = Name::data.substr(prev + 2);
            return arr;
        }

        template<typename F, typename Name>
        struct name_builder
        {
            static constexpr auto suf = detail::suffix<F>();
            static constexpr auto toks = split<Name>();
            static constexpr auto len = Name::data.size() + suf.size() - toks.size() + 6;
            static constexpr auto str = [] {
                std::array<char, len> arr = {};
                arr[0] = '?';
                int i = 1;
                for(int t = 0; t < toks.size(); t++)
                {
                    if(t > 0)
                        arr[i++] = '@';
                    for(auto c : toks[t])
                        arr[i++] = c;
                }

                arr[i++] = '@';
                arr[i++] = '@';
                arr[i++] = 'Y';

                for(auto c : suf)
                    arr[i++] = c;
                
                return arr;
            }();
        };
    }

    template<typename F, typename LambdaString>
    inline constexpr std::string_view name(LambdaString)
    {
        using Cs = detail::constexpr_string<LambdaString>;
        using N = detail::name_builder<F, Cs>;
        return {N::str.data(), N::len};
    }
}
```

[<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/1se56YPKE)