# Working with shared libraries - is it still just dlopen, dlsym et al?

Tags: c++, api, shared-libraries, dlsym

I've used `dlopen()`, `dlsym()` and friends in the past to load dynamic libraries manually at run-time - but that was in C. In C++ I would expect a somewhat higher-level-of-abstraction API, or at least - something which transparently takes care of name mangling for you, rather than only having to stick to `extern "C"` freestanding functions.

Well, according to the [C++ dlopen mini-howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/index.html), my expectations should be let down. Apparently it's just the POSIX API and nothing else. ... except that that document was last updated in 2006. That's the best I could find Googling.

So is that how things stand today still? In other words, have better/easier/nicer idiomatic ways of working with shared objects been devised over the past decade?

**Note:** I realize the C++ language standard doesn't quite address this (if at all), so I'm asking about what people use in practice.

Comment: There is no `dlopen` in either C or C++ standards so it's not very clear what your expectations are based upon. `dlopen` is a POSIX function.

Comment: @n.m.: Is this better?

Comment: There's no real way to "transparently take care of name mangling", however, there's no need to stick to `extern "C"` freestanding functions. You only need to call one such function once, get it to return a C++ object, and unfurl your C++ API from there.

Answer (score 1):

Martin Olivier is currently working on a C++ shared library dynamic loading library (sorry, tongue-twister): [dylib](https://github.com/martin-olivier/dylib/), with some support and advice from myself :-P

Specifically, he is [taking on](https://github.com/martin-olivier/dylib/issues/27) the challenge of name mangling. Too bad more people aren't involved who can invest the time to contribute additional name mangling conventions (e.g. MVSC).

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64077113/15416 by any chance?

Comment: @MSalters: I have not seen it. Actually, looking at, it could potentially be redone based on my own [constexpr type_name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64490578/1593077) (which is multi-compiler).

Comment: @MSalters: Ok, guess not. But that's certainly useful.