# Is there a reference for DLL function decorations in the lpProcName of GetProcAddress?

Tags: c++, dllimport, getprocaddress

I am trying to understand and anticipate how to reference functions in a DLL.

When we reference some functions in a couple of DLLs that we are accessing to do some calculations, in some of the functions, we simply use the process name as the argument `lpProcName` (e.g. `"my_calc_function"`). However, in some of the other functions (for a different DLL) we have to add various decorations to the `lpProcName` (e.g. `"?my_other_calc_function@@YA...."`)

in one case

```
m_lpfn_my_calc_function_pointer = (lpfn_my_calc_func)::GetProcAddress(m_hOneDll,"this_address_works");
```

in another case

```
m_lpfn_my_other_calc_function_pointer = (lpfn_my_calc_func)::GetProcAddress(m_hAnotherDll,"?this_address_has@@YAXNPEAN00PEAH@Z");
```

Both of these work, however, I would like to understand what the decorations mean and where I can reference them so that I can anticipate them when I am writing my code.

Comment: You may want to read up on name mangling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find the C++ mangled name to use in GetProcAddress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016732/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-c-mangled-name-to-use-in-getprocaddress)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it doesn't really help (other than pointing out that there is a name for what I am looking at!) - I am more looking for the system used in the 'mangling'

Answer (score 0):

The decorations (or, [name mangling](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B_name_mangling)) are based to the fact that you can have functions with the same name but different arguments.

DLL exports do not include function signatures, only a name. Therefore, the name is "decorated" to reflect on these arguments (classes, namespaces, arguments, return type, calling convention etc).

To remove the decoration, declare the function inside an `extern "C"` block.

Comment: thanks, I don't necessarily want to remove the name mangling, I recognise that it has a use for the various overloads, they are legacy DLLs and have lots of them. I am more looking for a system behind it... if there is any!