# How to remove mangling in C++

Tags: c++

I tried to create a function which is returning a `vector` in C++. But when it built to dll, the function name seems to be mangled.

I tried to use the `extern C` but the problem is return type `vector` cannot support if I use `extern C`

> Error : C Linkage function cannot return C++ class std:: Vector

Below is the code I am using

```
class __declspec(dllexport) TestClass
        {
        public:
            string sClassName;
            string sName;
            string sDescription;


        };


extern "C"
{
    vector<TestClass> __declspec(dllexport) GetInfoList();
}
```

Comment: What will you call it with?

Comment: Why do you try to do this?

Comment: C does not support a `vector`.  Try removing the `extern "C"` part.

Comment: Why it is problem that C++ function names are mangled for linker?

Comment: Removing extern c will result in name mangling. I am loading a dll dynamically and I want to call the function GetInfoList().

Comment: What compiler/platform are you using/targetting? Why do you need non-mangled names?

Comment: Since I am dynamically loading he DLL, i have to access the function using function name    GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "GetInfoList");

Comment: I am targeting like cross platform

Comment: You could try to mangle the names you pass to GetProcAddress instead of demangling your DLL.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016732/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-c-mangled-name-to-use-in-getprocaddress

Comment: It smells that you are over-optimistic about what you can dream of cross-platforming.  The std::vector<TestClass> using code in dll compiled with one compiler (say Visual Studio 2019) is not guaranteed to be compatible with std::vector<TestClass> compiled with some other compiler (say gcc of mingw-w64). Most likely it is not compatible at all.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Under MSVC 14.1, this is just a warning that can be silenced with `#pragma warning (suppress: 4190)` above your declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vector is C++ type and so cannot be directly given under extern "C". Give the function inside a class and export the class as C Type.

```
extern "C"
{
    class __declspec(dllexport) ClassToExport
    {
        vector<TestClass> GetInfoList();
    };
}
```

Now use this class object to axcess the function.

Answer (score 2):

We see it is not problem with easy solution. Here's an involved solution. Use a non-mangled name (extern "C") with GetProcAddress to access a special function in the higher level DLL. . Define all the functions you want to call, as virtuals,  in an abstract base class. Call that function above to retrieve the pointer P to a lazily instantiated concrete class with virtuals overriden. Invoke desired method through the pointer P.