# How to get the decorated name of a member function programmatically? (in MSVC will be better)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

The reason I want to understand it is that I'm going to make a DLL loader class like this:

```cpp
class DymanicLibraryLoader
{
    //some code
    template <typename FnPtrT>
    FnPtrT GetFunction(std::type_info& fn_type, std::string_view pretty_name)
    {
        //code
    }
};
//...
DynamicLibrary dll {...};
typedef void (SomeClass::* FnPtr)(int);
std::type_info& fntype = typeid(FnPtr);
auto fnptr = dll.GetFunction(fntype, "function")

//...
```

Comment: What makes you think that it is possible?

Comment: I got decorated name form std::type_info before. So I think maybe there are some ways to get decorated function name @Yunnosch

Comment: @Fa鸽 Have a look at [`__FUNCDNAME__`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019) and the answer to [Is there a way to find the C++ mangled name to use in GetProcAddress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016732/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-c-mangled-name-to-use-in-getprocaddress).

Comment: Function name listed in dll export table does not necessary match decorated or not decorated name.

Comment: @user7860670 really? I will try later

Comment: @dxiv if I use this, I need to register the decorated name in a hand made "type_info". I don't wish to work in this way if there is any other way to achieve this goal.

Comment: A pointer-to-member is not a regular pointer and you may or may not be able to get one from a DLL. Use `extern "C"` non-member functions and wrap anything you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `std::typeinfo::raw_name()`?

Comment: This approach is the closest way. Once you retrieved decorated function pointer name, you can rebuild function decorated name later with some hacks.

Answer (score -1):

The usual way would be to examine the DLL exports after building with a tool like dumpbin (included with MSVC).

```
dumpbin /exports <filename>.dll > exports.txt
```

then opening exports.txt and looking through the listed exports for the function(s) you want to load. I am not aware of any automated way to do this if you wish to use run-time symbol loading. (It is easy to perform load-time binding using __declspec(dllexport)/__declspec(dllimport)) but that is not available for run-time loading.

Comment: I need to get a decorated name by **C++ code**, not through dumpbin.exe