# How to view DLL functions?

Tags: windows, dll

I have a DLL file. How can I view the functions in that DLL?

Comment: this link servers well

 [view-contents-of-a-dll][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210305/view-contents-of-a-dll

Answer (score 95):

For native code it's probably best to use [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/).  It's also possible to use the [dumpbin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-options?view=msvc-170) command line utility that comes with Visual Studio.

Comment: With newer editions of VS, try DumpBin as an [External Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45477382/how-to-read-a-obj-file/49669631#49669631).

Comment: There is a Wikipedia article about Dependency Walker.  Apparently the program has become outdated and does not work with some newer features of Windows, but there is a replacement available: https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

Comment: This replacement doesn't work on my side. I wouldn't rely on it for ages as I did on late dependency walker. Sad news.

Comment: dependencywalker easy to use https://www.dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 70):

Use the free [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html), it is very easy to use.

Comment: @sumit can you be more specific? this tools works for me along the years.

Comment: Actually the tool works nice, plain and simple, just what I needed.

Comment: It's a great tool to generate a list of methods/functions, but it does not show the parameters of the methods (nor their types).

Comment: Very great to have something that is small and compact, and not some bloated product like the official MS products usually are.

Answer (score 54):

You may try the *Object Browser* in Visual Studio.

Select *Edit Custom Component Set*. From there, you can choose from a variety of .NET, COM or project libraries or just import external DLLs via Browse.

Comment: Visual Studio says "The selected component cannot be browsed" when using Browse and selecting DLL :( - http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(VS.Message.ObjectBrowserErrors)&rd=true

Comment: object browser has moved to `View`. And yes, it doesn't work (why would it, it's microsoft)

Comment: More a vendor than a MS problem. Probablay there's no typelib in the dll. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13903040/1614903

Comment: @HolgerBöhnke no typelib in userdll32 either

Comment: @Kimmax Yep, but user32.dll is a native windows DLL and not a COM server. Only COM servers (e.g. COM dlls, ActiveX controls, *.ocx...) possibly have typelibs, if they were compiled in, in the first place. For native (=non COM object)  DLLs some of the other tools mentioned here (dumpbin et. al.) may work. That is, if the DLL exports it's funtions by name and not by ordinal only.

Comment: @HolgerBöhnke thanks for the heads up. Interesting stuff to read into :)

Comment: It told me that the selected component could not be browsed.

Answer (score 52):

Use [`dumpbin` command-line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-command-line).

- `dumpbin /IMPORTS <path-to-file>` should provide the function imported into that DLL.
- `dumpbin /EXPORTS <path-to-file>` should provide the functions it exports.

Answer (score 14):

For .NET DLLs you can use [**ildasm**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: As ildasm is a Microsoft product and is installed on PC by default if you have Visual Studio installed.I believe it is the best option.It also has a UI so you don't need to use the command line. Thanks

Comment: It can be found:
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\<VERSION>\bin**

Answer (score 14):

Use dotPeek by JetBrains.

https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

> dotPeek is a free tool based on ReSharper. It can reliably decompile
>   any .NET assembly into C# or IL code.

Comment: So this is specific to DLLs using the .NET framework?

Answer (score 7):

Without telling us what language this DLL/assembly is from, we can only guess.

So how about [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/).

Comment: Then this should be your guy.

Comment: .net reflector used to be free, but it's a commercial product now. For .net dll's "JustDecompile" is a free alternative.

Comment: does decompiler only tell you what functions are there. can we see their implementation as well somwhow?

Answer (score 3):

For non .NET dlls, installing `binutils` on a Linux system presents the `objdump` command that can be used to display information of a dll.

```bash
objdump --private-headers <file.dll>
```

Look for the `Export Address Table` section in the output.

Answer (score 2):

If a DLL is written in one of the .NET languages and if you only want to view what functions, there is a reference to this DLL in the project.

Then doubleclick the DLL in the references folder and then you will see what functions it has in the OBJECT EXPLORER window.

If you would like to view the source code of that DLL file you can use a decompiler application such as .NET reflector.

Answer (score 0):

> .NET ildasm

ildasm helped and even dumped methods body, but to edit .DLL you also need any hex editor.

ildasm example to fix Help Viewer v2.x issue:
error: "An error occurred while updating content: File '???.cab' was not signed by Microsoft"

[here could be image](https://a.fsdn.com/con/app/proj/patch-hlp-21/screenshots/patch%20help%20dll.png/max/max/1)
[more example files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/patch-hlp-21)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a free,cli,portable software solution! Works on Linux,Windows,Mac OS

Provided that you have python.

you need to install pefile, no dependencies
`pip install pefile` or `pacman -S ${MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX}-python-pefile` if you are in msys2

```py
import pefile

def list_exports(file_path):
    pe = pefile.PE(file_path)
    # Check if the PE file has an export directory
    if hasattr(pe, 'DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT'):
        exports = []
        for exp in pe.DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT.symbols:
            export_dict = {
                'Address': hex(pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.ImageBase + exp.address),
                'Name': exp.name.decode() if exp.name else '',
                'Ordinal': exp.ordinal
            }
            exports.append(export_dict)
        return exports
    else:
        return None

# Usage
file_path = r"C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll"  # Replace with your file path
exports = list_exports(file_path)
if exports:
    for export in exports:
        print(f"Address: {export['Address']} Name: {export['Name']} Ordinal: {export['Ordinal']}")
else:
    print("No exports found.")
```