# how to find available functions/properties of a dll

Tags: vba, dll

I want to use functions/properties from 2-3 dlls. I could not find relevant details on the software because of which they get installed.

Could you please let me know how can i find these details? I am using Excel VBA to use these dlls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to view DLL functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438900/how-to-view-dll-functions)

Answer (score 2):

If you're adding a reference to a DLL into your VBA project, you can use 'Object Browser' (F2), select the DLL you added and the methods / classes / properties will be shown. With luck, your DLLs will be well documented - and easy to use.

Rgds

Answer (score 0):

I assume those are COM DLLs. In that case what you need is [OLE-COM Object Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), available as part of whatever is the latest [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b&displaylang=en).