# How discover a ClassID/COM UID of an Early Binding reference to use on Late Bindind?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, asp-classic

Putting it simple:

I need to discover the Namespace and all the public Methods exposed by a COM Library avaliable to be used.

I have this as an example:

[image: ClassID]

The closest place I have come is the CLASSES_ROOT folder in regedit, but there is no clue of the avaliable methods to be of use.

[image]

Comment: Is this for vba, vbscript, or asp?  In VBA, might one of the suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933484/how-to-find-available-functions-properties-of-a-dll) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210305/view-contents-of-a-dll)? I am not sure if the available methods can be determined programmatically

Comment: Are you looking for an [OLE/COM/ActiveX object viewer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/262134/113116)?

Comment: @Helen, I believe that will do the trick, thanks