# View contents of a dll

Tags: c#, dll, view

I am looking for a tool to view contents of a C# dll, preferably a free one. .Net Reflector used to be free but not anymore. It is an awesome tool and you can easily see all code down to the line. PE Explorer is another one I looked at but the Disassembler in it does not seem to output C# code. If you know any other tools, please share.
.Net reflector is the best one I know for the job, but just curious if there are any other options.

Comment: Looks to me like this is a dupe of [How to view DLL functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438900/how-to-view-dll-functions)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Telerik just came out with one:

http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiling.aspx

They said that it will ALWAYS be free.  They released it in response to .Net Reflector's change to a pay model.  Right now it is in an open beta (free to download now) and it works great

**Edit:** as of June 2014, "free" means you must use their bootstrap installer that attempts to bundle other (nonfree) applications. Also, you must register with their "Support System" to complete the install.

Comment: .NET Core exists for Linux/Mac, and Mono/C# does as well. Writing programs that generate .dlls isn't just a Windows thing.

Answer (score 30):

[DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) is awesome and free.

Comment: For those viewing in 2015: DotPeek is free(Reflector is not) and for me Dotpeek has been much more stable. I highly recommend it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is Windows-only.