# How to browse DLL file's contents

Tags: dll

I'm not able to open .dll's in Notepad.  How can I browse it's contents to view the code available in the class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view DLL functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438900/how-to-view-dll-functions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a good start using a dependency program like http://www.dependencywalker.com/.

This should tell you something about what functions the DLL exports.

Comment: Thank you. A lot of freeware I tried only works on .NET files. This one works on my non-.NET project.