# Why can't I browse dll to figure what's in it?: "Some components could not be browsed"

Tags: windows, dll, com, objectbrowser

I'm looking for a missing COM interface `X` which I suspect is defined in `Y.dll`. I can peek at this presumptive interface using

```
grep X Y.dll
```

which says "matches". Hurrah, suspicion confirmed!

Alas, when I use the Object Browser in Visual Studio Express, trying to add `Y.dll` to my Custom Component Set, I get the error: "Some components could not be browsed" in a pop-up window.

So what are the reasons I can't browse this dll? Can the COM interfaces deliberately or accidentally be protected, hidden, secured, or obscured? Obviously I need a primer!

Officially, all Microsoft knows about this seems to be generally devoid of insight:

> This error generally occurs when you attempt to add a file type that does not support object browsing, such as .htm 
>   and .txt files, in the Component Selector dialog box. The Object Browser supports file types such as .bsc, .olb, 
>   .tlb, .dll, .exe, and .ocx.

Seriously, what are the reasons for a dll or exe to not support object browsing? Any pointers to tutorials or books would be appreciated by this beginner! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COM Object browsers rely on [metadata (type libraries) exported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366757(v=vs.85).aspx)  by COM servers (dll, exe, ocx, etc).

The problem is that COM Servers are not required to export any metadata about which interfaces it implements. Unfortunately I have found quite a number of such servers (so one needs to know which CoClasses, Interfaces, etc are supported by other means).

Check if your COM Server (y.dll) contains a resource called "TYPELIB" similar to:

[image: COM typelib resource]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent response (but no luck...). Thanks!