# Get List of functions defined in DLL

Tags: c++, function, dll, export

I want to display list of functions one can access in DLL.
How can I do that?
I read about DbgHelp but don't know how to do it.

(It's a code request not a program that does it).

Comment: Your best bet would be to reverse engineer [dumpbin.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that's shipped with Visual Studio.

Comment: @devnull Why do that when the PE format is documented and there are APIs that parse it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This one needed to be closed first for this reason: Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**.

Comment: @devnull That seems impolite and needlessly aggressive to me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not sure what led you to think that I was being impolite/aggressive. That was not the intent, for sure.

Comment: in case anyone from google is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78232938/10000823

Answer (score 1):

Call the following command with the system function and catch the result

dumpbin /exports "C:....*path to your DLL*...."