# Error when attempting to call a C++ .dll library in R

Tags: r, dll

I have a library, let's say `mylibrary.dll`, that has c++ code that I want to run in R. I did this:

```
dyn.load("mylibrary.dll")
.Call("myfun")
```

I get:

```
Error in .Call("myfun") : C symbol name "myfun" not in load table
```

Now, I've seen several answers to similar problems, on here and on other websites, but when I attempted each solution, each seemed to be to require having access to the original source code, for example adding something like this: `extern "C"` to the C++ code or re-compiling the code in a certain way. All I have is a .dll file, and I'd like to use that directly to call from R the functions contained within it.

Comment: By the way, when I ran the first line of code I got this: `Warning message:
In inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :
  DLL attempted to change FPU control word from 8001f to 9001f`. I saw elsewhere that this can be ignored.

Comment: Why not include your code?

Comment: Have you tried looking through the load table? On Unix, you would use the `nm` command, but on Windows...I don't know. Maybe try some of the stuff on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438900/how-to-view-dll-functions) thread?

Comment: Rtools comes with `nm`, btw.

Comment: @nrussell, what code would you like me to include?

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyShiklomanov, I was able to figure it out from that thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: the name of the function was different than what I expected. I went to the thread that Alexey suggested in the comments, and from there was able to use one of the suggested tools (DLL export viewer) to get a list of the functions, where I found the correct name.

(Alas, I now need to figure out why R is locking up when I call the function, but my question here is done!)