# Flutter FFI bridge for C# DLL

Tags: c#, flutter, dll, ffi, dart-ffi

i'm using flutter desktop for my windows softwares, but i just bumped into ffi to make external dlls working.

If I make the library, i know i can use UnmanagedExport package to use the [DLLExport] notation and so flutter can use that method.
But now i got some dll library for C# from a card reader, and i always get errors like: **cannot find the symbol** or **not access pointer found**.

I also tried to make a wrapper in C# embedding the external dll (using reference or DLLImport). But i got the same result:
Exception: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Can't find access pointer with name 'sum' inside 'ClassLibrary1.dll'.
in FlutterBridge.originalFunct.sum(Int32 a, Int32 b)

(i translated the error from my main language).

Is there a way to use third party dll in flutter or to make wrapper/bridge to use them?
Also i got the same problem with a 32bit dll, since flutter only wants 64bit libraries.

My code just attach something:

flutter:

```
const dll = 'FlutterBridge.dll';
DynamicLibrary library;
library = DynamicLibrary.open(dll);

final addPointer = library.lookup<NativeFunction<AddFunc>>('mysum');
final add = addPointer.asFunction<Add>();

final result = add(_counter, 2);
```

C#

```
public class originalFunct
{
    [DllImport("ClassLibrary1.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 sum(Int32 a, Int32 b);
}

public class Class1
{
    [DllExport]
    public static Int32 mysum(Int32 a, Int32 b)
    {
        return originalFunct.sum(a, b);
    }
}
```

Obviously "ClassLibrary1.dll" is another classic C# library without UnmanagedExport to emulate external libs. I don't have the source code of the card reader dll, but i have the same error i get with my test because flutter can't access to the pointer.
Inside i have this code:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class SumClass
    {
        public static Int32 sum(Int32 a, Int32 b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope i explained in a nice way.

Here a screenshot of FlutterBridge.dll entrypoint
[image]

Comment: Having built your DLL, have you tried checking that the exports are there as expected? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438900/how-to-view-dll-functions

Comment: Dll i've built (FlutterBridge.dll) has the entrypoint with the exported function "mysum". The other one (ClassLibrary1.dll) hasn't. And that's the whole point! The original card reader dll hasn't too, but it works using it in C# (because it's make for C#). I'm trying to make a "bridge/wrapper" to make it usable in Flutter too.

Comment: Can you update the question with a screenshot of the exports (of FlutterBridge.dll)?

Comment: I uploaded the picture. However the problem isn't there. Because if, inside the flutterbridge.dll, i put a normal exported function like ```mysum2()``` and i return ```a+b;``` it works perfectly in flutter. The problem happens because i'm trying to access to ClassLibrary.dll functions which have no exported entrypoints (but it works if use it inside a C# app)

Comment: Have you been able to write any C# prog that can load your ClassLibrary1 dll?

Comment: Yes sure. I tried and it works perfectly

Comment: So, it looks like Dart can find the mysum/mysum2 methods in your bridge DLL. Also a C# program can find the sum method in ClassLibrary1.dll, But, when Dart loads the bridge DLL, then the loader can't find the dependency (ClassLibrary1.dll) needed for the bridge DLL. Do you need to make sure that they are in the same folder as each other, or in the Windows PATH?

Comment: No, wait. Dart can find "mysum" inside FlutterLibrary.dll. Inside "mysum" there is a DLLImport to ClassLibrary.dll to the function "sum". Now, if "sum" has an export (DLLExport of unmanagedexport package), everything works. If hasn't, it's basically the same as if i'm calling ClassLibrary.dll directly. "Cannot find the symbol" is the error. So the bridge is useless.