# How to call some function inside a dll?

Tags: java

I have a dll, say A.dll which expose an important method , say B, how can I call B with Java. I don't have the ability to modify dll itself.

Comment: Take a look at JNA : https://github.com/java-native-access/jna

Comment: do want to say that you want to call a function in a dll that you dont know if it exist ?

Comment: if it is the case [try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421102/list-all-exported-symbol-names-using-jna)