# C/C++: getting pointer to function without function name

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers

Question as above. For example, I have a custom DLL/binary/executable file, and I want to get an array of pointers, pointing to all functions stored in this file.

I thought about (1) virtual/pure virtual functions and (2) placing functions under a specific address, but I'm not sure about the first (I'd like to use `malloc` and raw data loading) and I cannot make second solution easy-to-use for potential modders.

How to do this in C/C++, is this possible at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you want to catch the functions? each one has different signature.

Comment: Could you please provide more information about why do you need these pointers and what are you going to do with them?
Do you want to implement a system to load mods to your application?

Comment: "*I thought about virtual/pure virtual functions and placing them under a specific address*" you really deserve your name creepyman900.

Comment: @DavidHaim What do you mean by "catching" functions?

Comment: how do you want the pointer to the function to look like? GetProcAddress returns void* and it expects you to know what signature the function has

Comment: @stgatilov Exactly, I want implementation like this. I just have troubles with getting pointers to custom calls.

Comment: @DavidHaim It has to look like `int ( *function )( void* )` if you mean this.

Comment: *ALL* the functions in the DLL are with this signature?  int ( function )( void )

Comment: Well, potential modder will have to declare them like that. I'm not an expert, and I don't know another solutions for that ;)

Comment: well, you can enumerate the functions of the dll with some ugly hack that gives their names. you can use GetProcAddres on them but it only return void*. you have to know their signature on the first place,.

Comment: @knm241 Sorry for my bad english; it had to be 2 different solutions.

Comment: @DavidHaim So there isn't any simple way to do what I want?

Comment: Don't mind :) It is just that you are using a very confusing terminology, I can't really figure out what you want to do.  If you just want to export a bunch of functions from a DLL just mark them for exportation and you can get their address with `GetProcAddress` using ordinal numbers or names. Then cast the `void*` to the appropriate function pointer.

Comment: So thank you, I will try, and when succeed I'll post the proper solution, just in case that somebody has same problem. :)

Comment: I can post an answer about how to implement modding system. However, your current question is more specific and a bit meaningless. If you are interested in modding systems, maybe you could provide more detail in question?

Comment: @stgatilov It's just my small game engine, I wanted this as a test modding system. But thanks ;)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128150/win32-api-to-enumerate-dll-export-functions for how to see all EXPORTED functions in DLL using WinAPI.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't get "all" functions in a file, because that's typically a bit ill-defined. And besides, what would you do with `__new_behind_the_scenes(__some_type_you_dont_understand&)`?

You are of course free to export `void(*ptrs[23])(void*)`, and it wouldn't be excessively hard to fill that array. What *would* be hard is to do something useful with such an API. And it will be hell for modders. Do they need to remember tho call `ptrs[16](&Widget)` to default-initialize a widget and `ptrs[17](&Widget)` to destroy it again?