# Windows API call to check if a .dll contains a particular procedure?

Tags: winapi, dll

Are there any Windows API calls that will accurately tell me whether a .dll contains a procedure?

I know about kernel32.dll's [LoadLibraryA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx), which (if successful) returns a handle to a specified <s>procedure</s> **[library]**, or (if unsuccessful) returns 0 and leaves a number on [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx). Unfortunately, when I ask LoadLibraryA to tell me the handle for a procedure (such as LoadLibraryA), it returns 0, and sets GetLastError to 126.  Obviously, LoadLibraryA was in kernel32.dll, but it could not find itself!

**[oops -- this was a bug.**  LoadLibraryA works fine when I ask for the handle for **kernel32.dll**, instead of LoadLibraryA. **]**

I want my program to be able to detect whether a procedure is available at run-time.  I do not want to include any other software, such as from nirsoft or Visual Studio.  Can this be done using just the Windows API?

I am running Windows 10.  The software I am writing uses the 32-bit Ascii versions of the Windows API calls.  The software will do its best to run on any NT-style windows from Windows NT through Windows 10, including WINE.  Some of these versions do not include particular procedures, and I want to be able to detect and work around such problems.

Comment: A similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128150/win32-api-to-enumerate-dll-export-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the true and trusted sequence:

- load the module using [`LoadLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx)
- search the proc with [`GetProcAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx)

You have to consider that in a 64 bit process (and specially on a WoW64 process as yours) there is a lot of thunking and redirecting going on behind the scenes, and also there is 'magic' going on with regard to ASCII vs. Unicode function versions (`xxA` vs. `xxW`). So I would take failure to 'find' LoadLibrary**A** in kernel**32**.dll on Windows **10** with a big grain of salt.

If you want to go a different route you would have to crack the PE and read the content yourself. Not impossible, read this 23 years old article that is still relevant: [Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx). There are tools that can help you like [dumpbin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx), but  I for one would not do that. I would trust `LoadLibrary` + `GetProcAddress`, that is **the** way.

Comment: Bingo!  I had been doing this (and it worked), but then I mistakenly changed the LoadLibrary call to look for the procedure name.  I changed it back to looking for the .dll, and now it works again.