# Get signatures of exported functions of a system DLL

Tags: c, dll, pdb-files, dbghelp

How do you get the signature of an exported function of a DLL? I know this is possible since a program analysis tool such as IDA (and ollydbg) manages to get the following for `GetVersionExA`:

```
push    offset VersionInformation ; lpVersionInformation
mov     edi, offset dword_4D3B94
mov     esi, offset aSS ; "%s - %s"
call    GetVersionExA
```

Using a hex editor to search through PDBs, I could not find the string `lpVersionInformation`. So where and how can I extract the signature?

Comment: I suppose these programs know the signature of most of the standard win32 functions

Comment: _[THIS link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1128453/645128)_ can help you to enumerate the exported functions using Win32 structs, not sure if you can extrapolate from there...

Comment: @ryyker Thanks for the suggestion. I am aware of this but I don't think parameter information is present in the dll itself.